# Google Sheets, Count Text Entries In One Row Based on Criteria, Only Using the Last 4 row Entries as the Range, Excluding Blanks

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I am trying to count the last 4 entries of specific text entries in one row that matches the text criteria based of another cell.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J (criteria) | K (results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X |  | Y | X | Y |  | Y | X |  | X | 2 |

Criteria in cell J would be X, and results in cell K would be 2 (H+D).
Criteria for Y could also be set somewhere, and results would be 2(G+E).

The sample data must be **only the last four** entries in the row. As additional data is entered, the formula must account for only using the last four entries.

Anyone have a solution?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(query(transpose({(A2:I2);column(A2:I2)}),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc limit 4"),J2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!   Is it possible to return the last 4 entries in specific cells?  Such as:

Comment: return the 3rd to last entry (assume numeric) from the row range in a cell, and the last entry from the row range in another cell?

Comment: I would imagine so, but it seems a bit different from your original question where you are only asking for a count of how many of the last four cells match a certain letter. Could you give a more concrete example or consider asking it as a separate question?